# Transpose every 2nd and 3rd line

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to transpose every second and third row to columns B and C and then preferably delete the old rows so that I don't have two unused rows in B and C. I tried recording a macro, which worked for only the selection I made. Then I tried deleting the specific selections and replacing them with an offset range but I keep getting an error in the PasteSpecial line.

```
Sub SortRawData()
'
' SortRawData Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count + 2, _
        Selection.Columns.Count).Select
    ActiveCell.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

I tried initially using Selection everywhere I have ActiveCell but neither seemed to work. I know I am missing the selection for the two rows I want to delete after I transpose the data into column B and C. What I have is a raw data dump of information that is formatted as:

Item1 Weight1 Color1 Item2 Weight2 Color2 Item 3 Weight 3 Color 3

I can get it to transpose one selection at a time by I can't seem to square away the automation of it.

```
Sub SortRawData2()
'
' SortRawData2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+w
'
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Rows("2:3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

This is the initial recorded macro and even it fails debugging at the PasteSpecial line. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, then code an autofilter to remove the empty rows:

```
Sub SortRawData2()
Dim lLastRow As Long, lLoop As Long

lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For lLoop = 1 To lLastRow Step 3
    Cells(lLoop, 2) = Cells(lLoop + 1, 1)
    Cells(lLoop, 3) = Cells(lLoop + 2, 1)
    Cells(lLoop + 1, 1).Resize(2).ClearContents
Next lLoop

With Range("A1:A" & lLastRow)
    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="="
    .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    .AutoFilter
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: From nutsch without Autofilter
`Sub SortRawData2()
    Dim lLastRow As Long, lLoop As Long
    lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rngDelete As Range

    For lLoop = 1 To lLastRow Step 3
        Cells(lLoop, 2) = Cells(lLoop + 1, 1)
        Cells(lLoop, 3) = Cells(lLoop + 2, 1)
        
        If rngDelete Is Nothing Then
            Set rngDelete = Union(Cells(lLoop + 1, 1), Cells(lLoop + 2, 1))
        Else
            Set rngDelete = Union(rngDelete, Cells(lLoop + 1, 1), Cells(lLoop + 2, 1))
        End If
    Next lLoop
    
    rngDelete.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub`

Comment: Thank you!  That did it exactly!  I need to learn a lot more about VBA, I have some web programming experience but VBA is just a language all its own!  It doesn't help that I see DIM and i think dimension but it seems to be something slightly different.

Comment: dim is the variable declaration. It's javascript's var, but with a variable type added to it.