# Macro for Transposing every 12 rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have data points for every month for over 50 years. So all the data are in a column and it is sorted by date then gives the data point of interest. I need to transpose all the months of each year. Here is an example of my data. All of the ... are where data continues on. What is on the left is what I have. What is on the right is what I need. How can I make a transposing loop for this?

[image]

Comment: Tongue in cheek answer:-  Open the Visual Basic Editor, insert module, start coding.  More "sane" response:- What code have you produced so far?  What problems are occurring when you run it?  What error messages are you getting?  Have you tried recording what happens when you do some of the steps manually?

Comment: you may want to look at reversing [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34166267/transpose-every-2nd-and-3rd-line?rq=1) and change the count to 12 instead of 2 or 3.  See if it help you out any:

Answer (score 1):

## NON VBA SOLUTION:

Lets assume your data in column format is set up with the date in column A and your values in column B.  If you were to place the values starting in D1, you could use the following formula:

```
=INDEX($B:$B,(COLUMN(D1)-COLUMN($D$1)+1)+(ROW(D1)-ROW($D$1))*12)
```

You can adjust the full column reference of B:B to suit your data.  Change D1 to whatever cell you choose for your top left corner.  Change the +1 to reflect the start row of your data.  The 12 represents the number of rows to essentially transpose.  Copy it across 12 columns, then copy the 12 cells down as far as needed.

Proof of Concept

[image: POF]

EDIT:

```
=INDEX($B:$B,(COLUMN(D1)-COLUMN($D$1)+ROW(B1))+(ROW(D1)-ROW($D$1))*12)
```

where B1 is the first row of your value to be transposed.

Comment: Excellent solution, but one caveat - it requires data to exist starting in row 1 (which it probably does), but if it doesn't (perhaps because of headings) you will need to add an offset to your calculation - e.g. if source data starts in row 5 then you will need to add 4 to your calculation.

Comment: Your edit has gotten rid of my caveat - I wish I could upvote twice!

Comment: The edit is there because of your positive comment along with the upvote.